# If else statement with 4 years variable including knowing which year it is

Tags: python, python-3.x

So the question stated is:
There is year 1950-2050 and we have the olympic games and football/soccer world championship.
The program should be able to tell which one it is based from these two variables and how the program should know is from the year between 1950-2050.
The program should also be able to tell when there wasn't a tournament for example 2001.

I just do not know how to tackle this problem. I am thinking of defining values such as

IOC = ( year: 1952, 1956,1960,1964,1968,1972,1976,1980,1984,1988,1992,1996,2000,2004,2008,2012,2016,2020,2024,2028,2032,2036,2040,2044,2048)
Fifacup = (1950,1954,1958,1962,1966,1970,1974,1978,1982,1986,1990,1994,1998,2002,2006,2010,2014,2018,2022,2026,2030,2034,2038,2042,2046,2050)

Then maybe I could code the program to be like a quiz of some sort like
print/input("Which tournament was held year 1954? Was it fifa world cup or the olympics?") Then maybe have some random factor that makes it randomize it between different year and when the person types wrong tournament then it says

print("Wrong tournament. Try again")

Or maybe could the program just understand the relation between year and tournament like and spouts out correct answers like:

print/input("write a year between 1950-2050:" and the person writes 1982
then the program says
fifa cup
and if wrong
"wrong cup"

maybe I can do a mix between all these two?
Some fact based program and quiz oriented

What do you guys think?

I have no clue how to code this would appreciate all the tips I can get but I am thinking in the lines like this

```py
import random

Questions = int(input("How many questions do you want?"))

IOC = (1952,1956,1960,1964,1968,1972,1976,1980,1984,1988,1992,1996,2000,2004,2008,2012,2016,2020,2024,2028,2032,2036,2040,2044,2048)

Fifacup =(1950,1954,1958,1962,1966,1970,1974,1978,1982,1986,1990,1994,1998,2002,2006,2010,2014,2018,2022,2026,2030,2034,2038,2042,2046,2050)

IOC = random.randint(1,2050)

Fifacup = random.randint(1,2050)

while True:
Answer = int(input("What is "+str(IOC)+"+"+str(Fifacup)+"? "))
if answer == (IOC+Fifacup):
print ("Very good! Correct")
```

Everything is wrong pretty much. I have no clue but my code is shoppy, it's like not even working together and I am a bit embarrassed to even post it. I would really appreciate some videos that is great at explaining this functions!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. After doing [more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Admonitions aside, it is very straightforward to check for membership in a list in python. Nearly any tutorial on lists will cover this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is well documented so you know what each line does and you have links to resources to learn about the things I used.

The script it's very tedious to use, it quits every time you insert something wrong, that's why I filled with various things to do, so you don't get all the job done and you can learn in the process, it even has a bug for you to fix in the firsts lines of code!

```py
import random
import sys

"""
In the case the user enters a non valid number we terminate the execution
TODO: ask again if the user doesn't introduce a valid integer
"""
try:
    number_of_questions = int(input('How many questions you want? '))
    if number_of_questions < 1:
        print("The number of questions must be greater than 0!")
except ValueError:
    print("The number of questions must be an integer!")
    sys.exit(1)

"""
You can read https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range to know why you need the + 1 and that 
the range function can take up to 3 arguments: start, stop and step
"""

last_year = 2050 + 1
"""
We use list comprehensions because they are fast and a beautiful way to iterate over things
you can get more info about them here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

We also use tuples insteand of lists, because tuples can't be mutated, and we dont want to change the years
"""
IOC = tuple(year for year in range(1952, last_year, 4))
FIFACUP = tuple(year for year in range(1950, last_year, 4))
"""
TODO: make this part without repeating the same text, and change the "was/will be" dymanically 
if you want to know how you can read about string interpolation or string formatting
"""

IOC_QUESTION = 'In which of this years was/will be the Olympics?'
FIFACUP_QUESTION = 'In which of this years was/will be the FIFA cup?'

answered_questions = 0
# We dont want an infinite bucle, so we will exit the program as soon as the user answered all the questions
while answered_questions < number_of_questions:
    subject = random.randrange(1, 2)  # we generate a number which can be 1 or 2
    if subject == 1:  # if the number is 1, we will ask about the olimpis
        print(IOC_QUESTION)
        correct_answer = random.choice(IOC)  # we pick a random valid answer
    if subject == 2:  # if the number is 2, we will ask about the fifa cup
        print(FIFACUP_QUESTION)
        correct_answer = random.choice(FIFACUP)  # we pick a random valid answer
    possible_answers = [
        correct_answer - random.randrange(1, 4),
        correct_answer + random.randrange(1, 4),
        correct_answer]  # we add and substract 1 to 3 years of the correct answer and save them in a tuple
    random.shuffle(possible_answers)  # we then shuffle the possible answers
    # We show the options for the user to pick
    answer = int(input(f'Choose one year in this list {possible_answers}:  '))
    # if the answer was not in the correct answers lists we show an error
    if answer not in possible_answers:
        """
        TODO: use string interpolation to show the answered value and the possibles values and
        ask again instead of exiting the program
        """
        print('You have to choose one of the offered answers!')
        sys.exit(1)
    if answer != correct_answer:
        # TODO: string interpolation and the try again
        print("That wasn't the correct answer!")
    if answer == correct_answer:
        print('Congratulations! that was the correct answer')  # TODO: string interpolation
    answered_questions += 1

print("You answered all the questions!")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for giving me your time! This is perfect